# Subqueries in 2 tables

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

I have 2 tables: machine and work.

Table:machine

```
machine_no       downtime      location
A1-100-01           2             A1
A1-100              1.5           A1
A1-200              3             A1
CC3-100-01          0.5           CC3
CC3-100             1.5           CC3
```

Table:work

```
machine_no         date
A1-100-01         2/4/14                 
A1-100            2/14/14
A1-200            2/6/14
CC3-100-01        3/15/14
CC3-100           3/2/14
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
machine_no        total_downtime                          month
  A1-100              3.5 (total of A1-100, A1-100-01)      02
  A1-200              3                                     02
```

When location A1 is selected.

```
SELECT machine_no, SUM(downtime) as total_downtime
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
         SUBSTR(machine_no, 1,
             CASE WHEN INSTR(machine_no, '-', 1, 2) = 0 
                THEN LENGTH(machine_no) 
                ELSE INSTR(machine_no, '-', 1, 2)-1 
                END) as machine_no,
         downtime 
  FROM machine 
  WHERE location='A1'
) InnerQuery
GROUP BY machine_no
```

How do I join table WORK and display the month? I'm using Oracle.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like that. I don't test this. Please test this: 

select substr(m.machine_no,1,6), sum(m.downtime), max(to_char(to_date(date, 'MM/DD/YY'), 'Month'))
from machine m join work w
on substr(m.machine_no,1,6)= substr(w.machine_no,1,6)
group by m.substr(m.machine_no,1,6)

Comment: So? No answer to be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The `month` column's semantics in your expected query result is unclear. Assuming that it is another aggregation "key", then your query would be

```
select
    regexp_substr(M.machine_no, '^[^-]+-[^-]+') as machine_no,
    sum(downtime) as total_downtime,
    to_char(W.date, 'mm') as month
from machine M
    join work W
        on W.machine_no = M.machine_no
group by
    regexp_substr(M.machine_no, '^[^-]+-[^-]+'),
    to_char(W.date, 'mm')
;
```

Assuming it is a (somehow) aggregated value, let's say via `min()` function, then your query would be

```
select
    regexp_substr(M.machine_no, '^[^-]+-[^-]+') as machine_no,
    sum(downtime) as total_downtime,
    min(to_char(W.date, 'mm')) as month
from machine M
    join work W
        on W.machine_no = M.machine_no
group by
    regexp_substr(M.machine_no, '^[^-]+-[^-]+')
;
```

Both of these, in addition, assume that the `(total of A1-100, A1-100-01)` in your expected result is just your note, not really a part of the result. But if not, then your query could be something along the lines of

```
select
    regexp_substr(M.machine_no, '^[^-]+-[^-]+') as machine_no,
    sum(downtime)||
        case when count(1) > 1 then
            ' (total of '||
            listagg(M.machine_no)
                within group (order by M.machine_no)||
            ')'
        end
        as total_downtime,
    to_char(W.date, 'mm') as month
from machine M
    join work W
        on W.machine_no = M.machine_no
group by
    regexp_substr(M.machine_no, '^[^-]+-[^-]+'),
    to_char(W.date, 'mm')
;
```

And even this works because of a few more assumptions about the (unsaid) properties of your `machine` and `work` tables, so I'm going to stop my answer here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

User regular expression to take sub string of machine_no and to_char to get the month

```
WITH machine(machine_no, downtime, location) as (
    select 'A1-100-01', 2, 'A1' from dual union all
    select 'A1-100', 1.5, 'A1' from dual union all
    select 'A1-200', 3, 'A1' from dual union all
    select 'CC3-100-01', 0.5, 'CC3' from dual union all
    select 'CC3-100', 1.5, 'CC3' from dual),
work(machine_no, ddate) as (
    select 'A1-100-01', to_date('2/4/14', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all                 
    select 'A1-100', to_date('2/14/14', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1-200', to_date('2/6/14', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'CC3-100-01', to_date('3/15/14', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'CC3-100', to_date('3/2/14', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual)
--End of data preparation    
SELECT regexp_substr(m.machine_no, '^\w+-\w+') AS machine_no, 
       sum(m.downtime) downtime_sum, 
       to_char(w.ddate , 'MM') MONTH
  FROM WORK w
  JOIN machine m ON m.machine_no = w.machine_no
 WHERE m.location = 'A1'
 GROUP BY regexp_substr(m.machine_no, '^\w+-\w+'), 
       to_char(w.ddate , 'MM');
```

Output:

```
| MACHINE_NO | DOWNTIME_SUM | MONTH |
|------------|--------------|-------|
|     A1-200 |            3 |    02 |
|     A1-100 |          3.5 |    02 |
```